# Use two OIDC Auth flows in parallel in Quarkus

Tags: rest, single-page-application, openid-connect, quarkus

I created a Rest-API and a frontend as a self contained system with Quarkus.
The frontend is served statically.

For Authentication i use a kleycloak server and have nearly the same configuration as in [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication) guide from quarkus.

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=frontend
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated
```

With this config i need to authenticate for the rest-api and the frontend. Thats what i want.
If i try to load the index.html i got redirected to keycloak and back. That works perfectly.

The problem is, that the same thing happens with the rest-api. I got redirected to keycloak with a "302 found"-status code. Here I would like to have an authentication with a bearer token and no redirect. Quarkus has the following configuration for this:

```
quarkus.oidc.application-type=service
```

That collides with the configuration for the frontend. Is there a way to use both, one for static files and one for the rest-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you're looking for a multi-tenant oidc setup(even though you're not designing tenants). The guide and example can be found [on the official quarkus website here](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-multitenancy).
This way you'll have similar setup:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=frontend
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated

quarkus.oidc.restapi.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth/your/path
quarkus.oidc.restapi.client-id=backend
quarkus.oidc.restapi.application-type=service
```

P.S you can replace `restapi` with more likable name.

Comment: hm.. but this way i need a custom tenantResolver, which checks if the call goes to the rest-api or to the static files. Then i need a own namespace for my rest-api or i have to check for present file ending. i thought a self contained system would be more of a typical use case and needs no workaround like this.

Comment: @Alex Okay, I see the issue, I'm only familiar with this solution sadly. If your project is new you can add `/api/` path prefix for your controllers to differentiate static content from api.

Comment: @Alex Do you have another solution in the meantime? I saw there is an application-type hybrid, but I didn't found a detailed description and how this works.

Comment: @Timz For my project we decided to use no authentication for the SPA frontend. We used `application-type=service` for the rest api and we used javascript to get the token from keycloak. [There](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect#single-page-applications) is now a short description of that in the guides. The only thing I could find about hybrid auth is [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/12320).