# Secure both REST API and Web Application being hosted on the same Quarkus instance?

Tags: quarkus

Back in the JBoss days, we could secure both an REST/API endpoint and WEB application frontend using a single deployment file.

Using Quarkus, I would like to host in a single instance, a Qute (Web Front-End) AND some JX-RS Rest endpoints for customers to use in their applications.

I don't see a way to currently support this other than to use `Multi-Tenant` setup and write custom code to parse the URL and call the correct provider? Is this the only option?

I also see that the paradigm seems to be hosting the FRONT end apps on one instance of Quarkus and the REST/API services on another (each with their own security workflow) and then if I need to call the REST services from the front-end, I pass the access token as the bearer.

Is this the officially supported options? or am I missing something on how to do what I originally want in one instance of Quarkus?

The only thing I found that is close to my question is this:
[Use two OIDC Auth flows in parallel in Quarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207891/use-two-oidc-auth-flows-in-parallel-in-quarkus?rq=2)

Thanks,

- Tim

Comment: As I am not familiar with the old JBoss paradigm you are referencing, mind expanding the description a little to give a better overview of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: We would like to host both a Web Front end (Qute, Vuejs, etc) AND some Rest Services (JX-RS) all within the same codebase and deploy it on Quarkus. We need the users hitting the web front end to be redirected to keycloak login page, and any users hitting the JX-RS services directly need to use Bearer token auth.
I'm not sure how we'd setup to different client configs in Quarkus.. one for Authorization workflow (Web) and another for Bearer all in the same `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

As far as supporting both authorization code flow and bearer tokens in the same codebase is concerned, simplest option is to use `quarkus.oidc.application-type=hybrid` - if the request has a bearer token - it is a bearer token authentication, otherwise a redirect. However, it covers the whole URL space, ex, given say `/web-ui` and `/jaxrs-service`, if someone accesses `/jaxrs-service` without a bearer token - it would still be a redirect. It would also require a single (realm) configuration covering both cases - which might not always work.
I think the best option is indeed use dynamic or static multi-tenant setup, it does not require a lot of effort - tenant resolver just checks the request path and decides which OIDC configuration has to deal with it.
As far as a token propagation from one endpoint to another one is concerned, it is very straightforward in Quarkus - say you have `web-app` endpoint authenticating users via code flow and Keycloak - now for the code flow access token to flow to the `service` endpoint one just needs to add `@AccessToken` annotation to the Resteasy Reactive Client interface.
How does it sound so far ? Thanks

Comment: See how to use annotations to resolve tenant IDs: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-multitenancy#resolving-tenant-identifiers-with-annotations. You can try to add an annotation like that on the `web-app` and `services endpoints` and OIDC configuration will be picked up without you having to write a custom resolver code

Comment: See also: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33495